# Chebyshev polynomials:proving $T_{n}(x)=U_{n}(x)-xU_{n−1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> To prove: $$T_n(x)=U_n(x)-xU_{n-1}(x)$$

Where $$T_n(x) = \text{Chebyshev polynomial of first kind}\\
 U_n(x) = \text{Chebyshev polynomial of second kind} $$

Comment: Use $T_n(\cos t)=\cos nt$ and $U_n(\cos t)=(\sin nt)/(\sin t)$.

Comment: Or use the linear recurrence and induction.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Correction: $$U_n\big(\cos (t)\big)=\dfrac{\sin\big((n+1)\,t\big)}{\sin(t)}\,.$$